# File is used by another process: How to solve this Error?

Tags: c#

I am trying to open a file, but I received:

The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. The File is an XML-Document. Can anyone help?

```
  string activeDirectory = @"X:\SubGraph\";
  string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(activeDirectory);
  foreach (string fileName in files){
  FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Comment: I think that you must to close the file after using it.

Comment: Depends if you're locking the file or something else is, if its something else and its locked against reading then you wont be able to, if its you, as John says, you need to close the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After using a file, you must to close it, I think:

```
foreach (string fileName in files)
{
    FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    //your code 
    file.Close();
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem when I worked with read/write from files. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this piece of code in some kind of loop you need to close your FileStream each time before finishing loop cycle.

```
file.Close();
```

Or use "using" construction like this:

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    // your code goes here
    file.Close();
}
```

Moreover, you better to accustom yourself to close all manually created streams after they are unnecessary anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Under some circumstances Windows locks the files. In your case can be:

1. Another process is locking the file. It might be windows or you av software or who knows.
   In order to discover who is locking the file you might several tools like [wholockme](http://www.dr-hoiby.com/WhoLockMe/) or [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/). These tools will tell you which process is locking the file and even allow you to unlock it.
2. Maybe you are locking your own file. In your code snippet seems you are not closing the file you are reading (Maybe you can edit your question and add all code). You should remember to include:

   file.Close();

   ... or file will remain open.